# R - how to write a function to read a CSV file

Tags: r, function, csv, read.csv

I have CSV files named "001", "002",..."100" stored in the working directory. I need to write a function to read any of these files. I tried the function below, but it doesn't work.

`func = function(ID)
{
inp = read.csv("ID.csv")
}`

I think this is because "ID.csv" is a character whereas ID is a numeric variable, but I am not sure. Can someone please explain the reason and suggest the right code?

Comment: concatain the `ID` and the `.csv` using `path = paste0(ID, ".csv")`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you sort of understand the problem. "ID.csv" is a string literal and it is literally looking for a file named ID.csv. If I were you, I would input ID as a string like you have it (i.e. "001" instead of 1). Then try this:

```
func = function(ID)
{
inp = read.csv(paste(ID,".csv",sep=""))
}
```

Comment: You forgot to add the last argument: sep="". The default for sep is a space (i.e. " ")

Comment: `paste0()` is the same as `paste(..., sep = "")`.

Comment: You forgot the last argument sep="". The default for separation between arguments to the paste() function is sep = " ", so the resulting name will be "001 .csv"

Comment: You are correct Des Grieux, I editted my answer to reflect this change.